# Where to ask question on IT management?

Tags: support

I have a question related to IT management, more specifically:
I'm beginning to document our application landscape. I have created a basic diagram and it keeps growing. I'd now like to list all applications in some sort of document or application.
My first reflex was to start with a simple spreadsheet and have the applications in rows, with columns being application owner, criticality and so on.
I'm looking for examples of such documents / catalogues and what they typically contain.

I'm having a hard time finding the "right" SE site for this, there had been an area51 proposal for "IT management", but is has been removed since.

Would PM.SE be the appropriate place? If not, where could I ask this?

Comment: There are tools for this. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management_database as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this in Meta before posting to the site itself - +1 for that.

In my opinion PM:SE is not a good fit for this question as it is not about the mechanics or theory of Project Management, even though it is likely some contributors here would have faced this task as part of a project at some time.

I am not aware of another SE site that would be relevant here because it is not really possible to answer a question that is essentially driven by the specific needs of one particular organisation.

I don't want to answer the question in Meta just because it is not a good fit for the main Q&A site, but what you are proposing is virtually identical to what I have seen done in the past.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to PMSE!

I believe that as of now, is hard to understand what your problem is, what you're trying to obtain by documenting your application landscape. Are you trying to meet some CMMi standards? Follow ITIL guidelines?

So long you can make the community understand that the problem you're addressing is a project management problem, it could fit.

As Marv states, however, you'll need to rethink your objective before asking otherwise your question is likely to be closed by community - not because they don't want to help (believe, PMSE Community is *very* helpful!) but because we just don't get it.

Cheers